# How from script in Matlab 2011a call function from Matlab 2013b?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I have a bunch of scipts and MEX-files that developed for MAtlab 2011a version. They doesn't work on 2013b version. But Matlab 2013b has a function with desired functionality... So how can I run scipts in Matlab 2011a, but with call one function from 2013b version?

I have error

```
Unexpected Standard exception from MEX file.
What() is:
Device -1: deviceMatrix(): no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

what looks like unsolvable for me because I cannot rewrite MEX-file.
There is CUDA-device which is detected fine by 2011a version.

I'm asking a particular question. I cannot rewrite MEX-file because I do not want to dive into it - it is not my code and I don't know CUDA and that way that I'm asking for looks like much simpler for me at least at this step of my work. Later if function will fits for me I will think about going to Matlab 2013b version.

Yes, CUDA is aviable on Matlab 2013b.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run the scripts in 2013b?

Comment: Wait, you're saying you don't have the C-code for the MEX file?

Comment: Is cuda available in your ML2013 installation? Try the example: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html?searchHighlight=gpuArray

Comment: It seems as a pain to need to run 2 matlab versions at the same time. You should recompile it for matlab 2013b if that is possible. Also all functions from matlab 2011a is not compatible and the other way around.

Comment: It then seems the easiest way to add the required path to matlab 2011b, so the new function can run there too. There will be some function overloading here, so make sure to isolate the need function as much as possible. It is never good to have code requiring 2 versions of a program to run. Even better would be to copy the matlab 2013b function and try to run it on your current matlab version, however I am not sure if you break the license agreement here, which is why I suggested adding the path